# JQUERY, i need to replace something

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

i need to replace **' / '** from list of genres that i add by clicking checkboxes, the first one is added without **' / '** so when i uncheck them and replace it with nothing but the first one can't be replaced cause it don't have **' / '** in front of it. So how can i do the replace operation so it will replace and the first one! [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MozzieMD/80tc37n2/1/)

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
  var spacer
  if(!$("#genre").val()){
    spacer = "";
  } else {
    spacer = " / ";
  }
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $("#genre").val($("#genre").val() + spacer + $(this).val());
  } else {
    $("#genre").val($("#genre").val().replace(' / ' + $(this).val(),""));
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an online demo..?

Comment: you need to provide html to used to produle issue as well as a better explanation of expected results. A demo in jsfiddle.net would help a lot

Comment: calculate full category again so that you don't have to write such a complicated code.

Comment: Added JSFiddle link there

Comment: Added my answer. please add comment if not fulfilling your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will be useful. The order of addition will not be preserve.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
    var checkList = [];
    $("#genreslist").find("input").each(function () {
        if (this.checked) checkList.push(this.value);
    });
    $("#genre").val(checkList.join("/"));
});
```

Fiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/80tc37n2/4/)

To preserve order you can do :

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
  var spacer = "";
    var value = $("#genre").val();
  if($("#genre").val()){
    spacer = " / ";
  }
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $("#genre").val(value + spacer + $(this).val());
  } else {
      var endSpacer = "";
      if(value.indexOf($(this).val()) == 0)
      {
          spacer="";
          endSpacer = value.length > $(this).val().length ? " / " : "";
      }
      $("#genre").val($("#genre").val().replace(spacer + $(this).val() + endSpacer,""));
  }
});
```

Fiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/80tc37n2/5/)

Comment: But it's possible to preserve the order? will be awesome!